# Php and mysql weird error with select

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm a beginner in web design and I have this problem. I'm trying to create a login page but when I try to create the login it throws a error as follows:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':username and passwordhash=:passwordhashed)' at line 1

With php code of

```
Try { 
//    $SQL = 'INSERT INTO Passwords (username, password, passwordhashed) VALUES (:username,:password,:passwordhashed);';
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$PasswordHashed = sha1($password);
echo "Username: ". $username ."<br> Password: ". $password . "<br> PasswordHashed: " . $PasswordHashed;
$SQL = null;
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM BlaBla WHERE (username=:username and passwordhash=:passwordhashed);";
$Statement = $MySQL->prepare($SQL);
$Statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
$Statement->bindValue(':passwordhashed', $PasswordHashed);
$Statement->execute();
$Statement = $MySQL->query($SQL);
if ($Statement->rowCount() < 1 ) {
    echo 'NOPE';
} else {
    echo 'welcome back '. $username;
}

} catch(PDOException $e) {
$ErrorTitle = 'Error';
$Error = "error writing to database";
$ErrorInfo = '<p>Please contact administrator at stephan.littel@stecasso.nl</p> <br> <p>'. $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
include './HTML/Error.php';
exit();
}
```

I don't know what the error is. Could anyone help me?

Comment: @devlincarnate: that's PDO. mysqli doesn't have named placeholders.

Comment: Try removing the last: `$MySQL->query($SQL)`. You have already executed the statement with `$MySQL->execute()`.

Comment: $Statement = $MySQL->query($SQL);

Comment: SHA1 is not a secure way to hash passwords. You need to [switch to password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: @Wax that's right, `$Statement->execute()` does the execution

Comment: You would think that I would learn to finish my first cup of coffee before visiting SO.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
$Statement = $MySQL->prepare($SQL);
   ^---your prepared statement
$Statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
$Statement->bindValue(':passwordhashed', $PasswordHashed);
$Statement->execute();
$Statement = $MySQL->query($SQL);
                        ^----raw queries have no placeholders
```

You prepare a statement, and execute it. But then you do a RAW query with the same SQL, replacing the result of the prepared version. You cannot use placeholders in a raw query like that. Hence your error.

That final ->query() call is useless and redundant.

Comment: `near ':username and passwordhash=:passwordhashed)' at line 1` - that to me doesn't sound like it's coming from `$Statement = $MySQL->query($SQL);` but more like they're probably using mysqli_ to connect with. Edit: Ok I was wrong. That could have been a possible issue also.

Comment: mysql reports the first place that something made no grammatical sense, which is the placeholder. since `->query()` doesn't do placeholders, the :username placeholder is the first place the query statement stops making sense.

Comment: Yeah I know Marc. But I did edit my comment above which I have seen happen before, where the person was using mysqli to connect with, then using PDO to query with.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Problem was I used query and execute. My fault of slopy bug tracking.

Comment: You found it by yourself?